# Plausibility of hollow horns?

Tags: science-based, creature-design

I am working on creating a species where they have hollow horns (the horns have evolved to the point of being mostly for display and minor neck protection so they do not have to be super sturdy) so as to not weigh them down too much when jumping, gliding, and flying between trees. If it helps any, they are around the size of a cat, have hollow bones, are omnivorous mammals, and live on an isolated island humans have yet to find. Therefore they cannot come into contact with humans. So far I have yet to find any creatures with hollow horns.

So I am looking for a way for them to have hollow horns, without it being through gene editing from another species, and with it being plausible in science.

Comment: Narwhals, Narwhals / Swimming in the ocean / Causing a commotion / Coz they are so awesome

Comment: Just as small thing: I love cheating, and you should too. Why not have the horns internally be more like a structured foam, with lots of air pockets? They'd be both strong and light.

Comment: @Mephistopheles I know I _can_ cheat. But the challenge i've set myself for these dragons is as little cheating as possible, so that they could be very much scientifically plausible. I even have a reason for them having horns, despite being so small. So it's mostly just figuring out the most plausible light version of them.

Comment: But nature DOES cheat all the time, you just simply give it a push. Surprisingly sophisticated structures aren't an unseen thing there either.

Comment: @Mephistopheles fair enough. though I think the option i'm going with is cheaty enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible.

Hollow keratinous structures already exist, (feathers and quills) they just need to be rooted down into a socket in the skull otherwise the connection is far too weak to hold them on.

Horns, claws, hair,nails, are all made of keratin. we give them different names based on shape and were they grow on the body but the process is more or less identical in all of them. the only issue you have is anchorage, but you can use  other hollow structures (hair and feathers again) for inspiration.
So they don't grow exactly like horns but more like giant hedgehog quills or feathers without vanes. That means they start deep in the flesh likely in a bony socket for stability since we are going for large structures.  Since you see hollow keratin structures in both birds and mammals there is no reason it can't evolve. Mostly hollow in the case of porcupine quills feathers are actually doubly hollow, the feather shaft is hollow and feathers grow as a hollow tube that unfolds to form a flat shape.

They may have to shed and regrow them periodically, otherwise they will eventually wear through creating a perfect breeding ground for bacteria (an open tube exposed to the weather), but that could be as rare as once every few years. Depending on how long they live they might not need to do it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a handy diagram from wikipedia:

[image: horn diagram]

Not all horns (or things that look like horns, like antlers, which I'll ignore here) are quite like this, but it is a good start. You can see why L.Dutch said horns were already hollow... *technically*, the actual horn *material* is hollow, but the horn *structure* often contains other stuff, like a bony core, which provides much of the horn's strength and supports the cellular matrix which grows the outer layer of the horn. Here's a goat skull, minus the horn covering, so you can see that they're mostly bone.

[image: goat skull]

[Rhino horns](https://people.ohio.edu/witmerl/2006_rhino_horn.htm) don't have a bony core, but they're also not hollow... indeed, the core of the horn is the densest area, and is responsible for the horns strength.

You've a few options here. Firstly, once the horn is fully grown, the bony core could be broken down. Maybe the bony core isn't really very body at all, but more fleshy and marrow like. Maybe the bone core is more like an avian bone, filled with large voids.

In any case, it seems unlikely that you'd get something horn shaped which tapered or had a closed tip *and* was completely hollow at every stage of its growth. It wouldn't be impossible... weird biological structures pop up all the time, but it would not be very strong which rather calls into question the usefulness of this sort of horn in the first place. Something like a rhino horn with a circular growth area where the tip fuses together as it grows *might* work, but you might end up with a weird tubular horn instead especially if it were damage during early growth. Horns with a lightweight bone core would be much more sturdy and useful and more likely to retain their shape.

Comment: If the use of the horn is purely sexual display having it be hollow at all times might be an advantage. “Look at me, I’m young, I’m Massively horny and I can still Do the mating dance at full speed! Pick me!”

Comment: @JoeBloggs you'll be able to recognise the young ones because they have one half-horn and one bent horn, no doubt.

Comment: You’ll probably be able to spot the young ones because they’ll have no idea what to do with their huge... horn.

Comment: @JoeBloggs "_oh my god look at the size of my things! i'm going to stick them in so many places!_"

Comment: *Horn crumpling intensifies*

Comment: What you say makes sense. Except I don't quite understand what you mean with the tip fusing together as it grows for the idea of something like a rhino horn.

Comment: also, @JoeBloggs Display doesn't always mean sexual display, especially not as humans interpret it. In this case, it means a threat to predators, as well as a "hey, I'm healthy and strong enough to grow horns while surviving." Much more useful that way.

Comment: @Snifferdragon: Sure, but the euphemisms don’t work nearly as well that way!

Answer (score 2):

**[Parasaurolophus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasaurolophus)** was a very distinctive species of dinosaur that had a large hollow crest as part of its skull. This crest was most likely used as a resonating chamber for the animal's calls, and had a path from its nasal cavity, looping around inside the crest and then back out of its mouth.

[image: Parasaurolophus skull]

Your cat's hollow horns could have evolved as resonating chambers as well. Take the diagram from Starfish Prime's answer:

[image: Horn]

The gap between the bone and the horn outer casing being hollow already is helpful. What you then need is the nasal cavity to extend under the skin and through a void into the horn structure, then back down the other side and out of the other nostril or mouth.

In its ancestral forms, the horn could have started much closer to the nose which would allow for minor mutations to the palate to open up into the horn and start the process, with later forms having the horn further and further back on the head to maximise the space available for resonance.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that seems plausible. They're light, and and I'm guessing small. I don't know if they could be bone unless they had an opening. I think they should be an organ they use for sound generation (similarly to brass instruments).

Answer (score -1):

Hollow horns are already present in some species, else it would have not been possible for humans to use them as musical instruments.

Therefore it's not an impossible feature to have, for the very reasons you list: light weight and balance.

What I find a bit more problematic is the size of your beasts: on the lower end of horned animals we have goats and sheeps, which are bigger than a cat.

You should probably increase their size.

Comment: Horns aren't actually hollow when they are growing on the animal. The bone on the inside of the horn material is removed before humans use the horn. This can occur naturally too, as the keratin the surface of the horn is made of, is much harder than the inside bone that'll quickly degrade when exposed to the elements.

Comment: Also, something like [insular dwarfism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insular_dwarfism) could easily explain the size.

Comment: Rabbits are about the size of cats and I have read about some rabbits developing a condition which results in "horns" appearing on their heads. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shope_papilloma_virus

Comment: @MichaelMortensen not true. The horns themselves are hollow, ceratinous, structures fitting over a bony or fleshy structure.

Comment: Actually, the smallest horned creature was the Horned Gopher. It was 30 cm long, as opposed to the average cat, which is about 46 cm without their tail. If you want a living example, the Dik-dik, a very small antelope of sorts, is 50 - 70 cm long.